# Когда я нажимаю на кнопку в попытке открыть следующее activity приложение вылетает (Main activity на Kotlin а registration на java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Когда я нажимаю на кнопку в попытке открыть следующее activity приложение вылетает (хочу открыть fctivity registration) вот код:

```
package com.greenprojectinfo.ideabank

import android.content.Intent
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val btnTA = findViewById(R.id.btnTA)
        btnTA.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Donation::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val btnDon = findViewById(R.id.btnDon)
        btnDon.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, TakingAway::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
        val btnMEN = findViewById(R.id.btnMEN)
        btnMEN.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Mentor::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

        val btnMon = findViewById(R.id.btnMon)
        btnMon.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Fond::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }
        val btnBtn = findViewById(R.id.btnBtn)
        btnBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, Registration::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)

        }

    }



    }
```

Comment: а в логах что пишет?

Comment: а этот активити есть в манифесте?